# OAuth2: No "Sign In with LinkedIn" product in my app settings

Tags: linkedin-api

I'd like to set up OAuth login via LinkedIn. Every tutorial and the docs are stating I need to add the "Sign in with LinkedIn" product, but there's no such item on the list. The app settings are complete, the app is verified and I don't see any issue or warning on its pages.

**UPDATE:** "Sign in with OpenID Connect" isn't what I'm looking for!

Here's the complete list that I get:
[image]

How can I enable OAuth for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it [turns out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin), LinkedIn has recently deprecated this login method, and the related scopes, as of 1 August 2023:

> This version of Sign In with LinkedIn has been deprecated as of **August 1, 2023**. For all Sign In with LinkedIn implementations going forward, please refer to Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect.

That's why all tutorials are now obsolete. And apps need to migrate to OIDC if they're willing to support LinkedIn login.

Funny it's nearly impossible to find any news about this transition, and even Microsoft Support seem to be in the dark about that.

Answer (score -1):

It's the fifth one in your screenshot. Some API docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2).

Comment: No. I don't need OIDC, I need OAuth2. It's a different protocol and it has different scopes.

Comment: Is there a particular concern you have about using OIDC? OIDC is built on top of OAuth 2.0, so if you're using OIDC, you're using OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Yes. My concern is that [goth doesn't support auth via OIDC](https://github.com/markbates/goth/issues/519).